# Java Swing Validation

Tags: java, swing, validation

I am using the SimpleValidationAPI for my Swing Application. I have imported it into my application and attempted to follow the example as per this [link](http://java.dzone.com/news/how-quickly-add-validation)

Unfortunately - the Validators enumerator is not resolving on my class path - despite other classes in the JAR clearly being on the build path. I wonder if anyone knows why this might be happening?

So - this leaves me with a predicament. I dont want to have to write onerous code to perform fairly ubiquitous validation procedures.

Can anyone recommend another decent validation framework for Swing / AWT components that emulates what I ***should*** be able to do with the SimpleValidationAPI?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JGoodies` has a [validation framework](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/validation/). I do not have any experience with it, but I do have experience with other `JGoodies` libraries (their Forms framework) and that works rather well.